# Reusing Mac OS X checkmark icon

Tags: objective-c, icons, standards

I've been looking at the possibility of reusing some icons of Mac OS X, most notably the green checkmark (similar to the one in Automator).

However, I could not find that icon in any of the application packages or on Apple's documentation.

While I can create the image myself, I'd rather reuse something that's supposed to be already there (if it really is there).

Is there a struct/class that'll help me reuse that particular icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only system-defined icons you can use are available in Interface Builder. There are no other APIs to get those icons. And you cannot simply take icons from other apps, they are copyrighted. If you want that icon you’ll have to make it yourself or license it from someone.